# Working with big amount of data. PHP Sessions or accessing data every time?

Tags: php, mysql, session, database-performance

We have this web app we're working on where users store some bookmarks (url/title/shortkey/times url clicked) etc.

Every time the user refreshes the page, this data is being retrieved from the database (different server). Logically, so you're able to view the bookmarks. All the bookmarks are in the  of every page of the app; so where every the user clicks, those data has to be parsed.

Is it better to store this data into Sessions or keep requesting every time from the database? What do developers usually do in this situations?

I would imagine, every refresh button from approximately 1000 users with approximately 100 bookmarks (approx. 100 characters each row), thats a ton of data every minute to be accessed.

A pretty similar example based on our web app is the [twitter's favourites](https://twitter.com/favorites). Every time you access this page, does it request's your favourites from the database, or are the favourites stored into sessions based on your ID?

Comment: Why don't you try both ways and time the results. It would normally be faster to retrieve data from a local server than from a remote one, but that depends on the specs of both machines, the configurations and hardware in use

Comment: The reasons being is because im not sure if you can test case an actual example of what 1000 or 10,000 users would actually do. All this bookmarks are in the header of every page of the app. So where ever the user clicks, the app will show him all these data. (retrieve or php session)

Answer (score 1):

Cache the bookmarks to a flat file to include where relevant (even the structured nature if you let them build a folder structure) - if you store the bookmarks in a db then you can reconstitue from those results. Simply delete the file when they CRUD any bookmark.

If you come up with a suitable file naming scheme - like userId.txt - managing will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to keep track of the needed data and it will be very fast since its in memory.